# Check if variable is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, pug

I've tried both these:

```
if foo
  if foo[0] == bar.baz[0]
    input.form-control-success(type="text")
  else
    input.form-control-danger(type="text")
else
  input(type="text")
```

```
unless foo === undefined
  if foo[0] == bar.baz[0]
    input.form-control-success(type="text")
  else
    input.form-control-danger(type="text")
else
  input(type="text")
```

But in both cases I get the error

> Cannot read property '0' of undefined

on the line `if foo[0] == bar.baz[0]`.

---

The situation is that sometimes `foo` is passed to pug, and sometimes it isn't.

`foo` is an array when it is passed, and if it is passed I need to do something based on whether it's x<sup>th</sup> element is the same as another array's x<sup>th</sup> element.

Comment: Try `if foo !== undefined` instead `if foo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

undefined is falsy in js...it looks like bar.baz may be your culprit.

Comment: Your initial assumption was correct. You can't inspect these variables in chrome though because they're compiled server-side

Answer (score 3):

You can use [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) to check if a variable is `undefined`. It always returns a `string`.

```js
if (typeof foo === 'undefined') {
  console.log('foo is undefined');
}

var foo = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

if (typeof foo !== 'undefined') {
  // access elements
  console.log(foo[0] + ', ' + foo[1] + ', ' + foo[2]);
}
```